# What am I doin wrong with Joomla template?

Tags: templates, web, joomla

[When I uploaded the right template that suits my Joomla version it shows this. What to do to my template that'll work properly?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9CHl.jpg)

Comment: What is wrong with this picture? Should it be obvious to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the position of the modules that you would like to show on your site to the module positions that the template uses.

http://www.astemplates.com/joomla-template-documentation/234-147-template-module-positions

Comment: But it's all have it's positions, or not?

Comment: Templates don't always use the same module positions. You have to have a module published to the position used in the template in order for it to show on your site. Template releases from the same publisher may use the same but that's not always the case.

Comment: Where I can find templates that will not cost me these problems 'n will work perfectly?)

Comment: pretty much any template will have this issue. If you plan on changing your template often, you'll want to use templates by the same developer. We use rocketheme but there's plenty of other templates that provide excellent features. You can always build your own. I've done that a couple times using Gantry.

Comment: what is the best way to create a website?